User stories can be moved from BA to Development team, or a separate story has to be created for Developers and further for QA?
After gathering 10 user stories through BAs, during grooming, should I directly assign them to developers or create new user stories for development.
Wouldn't this create duplicates, given that each new ticket would likely have the same name as the original user story.

I am assuming you are talking about Scrum, since you said "grooming" (aka refinement) and "sprint planning".

should I directly assign them to developers or create new user stories for development.

You should mark them as ready to go into a sprint during grooming. Then you should add them to a sprint during sprint planning with your team.
And then, if and when a specific developer works on it during that sprint, you can assign it to them.
There is no point in making copies. There are multiple steps of refinement, from the idea, to having a good user story, to having enough details for the developers, to having a good test, those details are all cumulative. You can always add them, they never change or detract from earlier steps. They build upon each other. So there is no reason to have more than one ticket for the user story itself.
Now if you want to track development tasks to complete this user story, maybe you need an UI, you need backend services, you need database changes, you need graphics and texting, code reviews, developer testing, then feel free to use whatever your system provides to track that as a detail of your user story. Whatever your system calls "sub tickets", in TFS it's called a "task", in Jira a "subtask", other systems will have similar names.
So to summarize: do not make copies. Have one item flow through your process. If one process step has multiple smaller tasks, and you need to track them, use sub-tickets to the user story.

Followup Question - If same story moves for Grooming -> development. How to mark them or label it Grooming phase is completed or know % completion of groomed items since users will change if assigned to developer.
Stories -
1
2
.
.
.
10
Development
Phase 1 -
1
.
.
4
Phase 2 -
5
.
.
10
QA
Phase 1 -
1
.
.
4
Phase 2 -
5
.
.
10

Well, I guess it depends on what you use. If you use pen and paper, you could just write "ready for development" on it, if you use an electronic system it might be a field where you can fill this information in. In TFS I think it's called the "area" where it moves from "refinement" to "ready-for-development", but those areas where defined by our PO, they don't come with the tool. You could also define states for example in Jira. Name them "In Refinement" "Ready for development", "In Development" etc...

Understood, Thank you. Have couple of questions while implementing them; ll post as a new Question.

If you are truly following scrum, your process needs to allow for ready for development being a temporary state. If a story is not high enough priority to go into a sprint, it is possible that the story will need more refinement based on learnings from that sprint. The longer a story spends waiting,  the higher the chance of this.
